# Addressing a basement window leak

Tags: basement, leak

History - Bought my house, new, in '96. A poured cement basement floor. I wanted to finish the basement, but had heard of neighbors whose floors got wet in a heavy rain. Not through a wall or window, the cement, a bit porous, I guess, just got dark and then a puddle. So, I waited 10 years to confirm my location wasn't going to do this.

Now, we recently had a fast storm, and I got water in my basement, just the corner by this window. I'd like to find a solution so this never happens again. Is this a case where a plastic bubble looking cover is enough? Or might I need to get a pro to replace the window (as if I could get a local pro to respond for such a small job, even 2 of these might not get a response).

[image]

This is the cover I am describing -

[image]

Comment: If it is the window itself leaking, the bubble or just sealing/caulking the window should do.  There might also be a small crack in the wall, that will require digging and fixing.  My own experience(much more than a puddle) is that ten years not enough time, maybe 50 to 100 years before finishing the basement.

Comment: That bubble will prevent rain from directly attacking the window, which is minimal and will not cause flooding. But since the window is lower than ground, and you have no drainage that will cause the problem. If you dig a trench and install drainage the will last forever. **you can see how high the water was** by marking on the window

Comment: Before you do anything, clean up at area, open the window and examine the weather stripping or sealing strips on the window. They could be corroded  or worn. They have to be maintained like everything else in the house.  Also, check after rain storms to see if you can determine where the leak might have come from.

Comment: @JACK - "After"? Whatever I do, I will grab a beverage, food, and book, and sit by the window for the entire weather event. Thx.

Comment: You need to work on the drainage, so that water doesn't pool against the window (as it's clearly done in the past).

Comment: Hmmm, thanks. Curious that this is just starting now. It didn't seem like anything has changed. Surprised that I went from dry to having the issue. I suppose it wouldn't hurt to add topsoil to get the water moving away from the house. .

Comment: Is the water coming in at the lower corner of the window frame, or is it just showing up on the wall below the window opening.  You may have a hairline crack in that location that has developed over the years.

Comment: I posted before I dug into the issue from the inside. JACK's advice may do it. The inside window frame was rusted, and the wood, wet, there. I pulled out the molding, and window. Brushed it with a metal bristle brush, put it back, and caulked with Mortite around the perimeter. Tomorrow, I'll do this with the second window (there are 2 in the basement) and will test by using a hose and spray water at both windows. I remain hopeful the foundation isn't cracked and this solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I'd address with a leak at a basement window as shown would be the grade around the house. I'd also glance up to see if there was a gutter problem.

Why not grab a plastic bubble first thing? The amount of water falling from the sky directly into that opening would be trivial. It's probably got a little roof overhang coverage above, and it has space below the sill to collect any water that gets in until it drains away.

But the amount of water that can flow into that opening if the ground is not correctly sloped to carry water away from the house, or if a gutter is overflowing and dumping on it, is huge. And neither one of those is likely to be improved significantly by a plastic bubble.

So, that's what I'd suspect and check (and correct, if need be) first. The basics...